# Tracking a short

Tags: laptop, motherboard, battery, power

I was looking at a thread posted on earlier [Laptop charger dying after plugging in?](https://superuser.com/questions/284956/laptop-charger-dying-after-plugging-in) 
talking about a power issue with a laptop or the charger. I have done some testing and concluded that the short is not in my battery or the charger.

One of the posts had mentioned looking for the short internally on the motherboard or power connector. I am in need of information on the tools required and the process of the procedure so i can track down the busted part.

Comment: You have not indicated why you think there's a "short" somewhere.  Please do not misuse the term "short" if you just really mean "an electrical problem".  I've heard/read too many people describe a problem as an "electrical short" when they wouldn't know the difference between a short versus an open.

Comment: You are correct, I do not know weather or not there is a short, just felt like the best term to use, all i know is that there is an electrical problem either with the power connector or with something onn the mother board and need to find the issue

Comment: The origional problem consisted in the led on my power brick being on but when i plugged the charger into my laptop it immediately turns off.  Tested the cord and its fine and tried to run the laptop with the battery out but still plugged in and that didnt work.  This leads me to believe that there is an "electrical problem" internally with the laptop, i need to be able to find it in order to replace the part